# Problema al crear/actualizar id de una entidad con JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy montando un CRUD para mi aplicación, y pretendo que al crear y actualizar mi objeto en mi base de datos (mysql), no se pierda el `id`, si no que siga siendo el mismo.

Lo explico con ejemplos:

Al hacer un `POST` para guardar una entidad en base de datos, pretendo que se cree con el identificador que corresponda (por ejemplo, id = 100). Esto no debe informarlo el usuario, si no que con la anotación `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` es suficiente.

El problema lo tengo en el `PUT`, al intentar actualizar mi entidad. El usuario pasa el objeto de entidad que quiere modificar junto con el identificador.
El servicio, primero la entidad en base de datos, y posteriormente la crea de nuevo (ya actualizada, con el mismo identificador que el usuario ha pasado). Sin embargo, como mi clase de Entidad tiene la anotación de `@GeneratedValue`, lo que hace JPA es ignorar el `id` pasado por el usuario, y asignar el que toque (en este caso el id = 101).

Lo que necesito es que mi entidad ya actualizada siga teniendo como valor de id = 100.

Ejemplo de mi clase entidad:

```
    @Entity
    @Table
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Document {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        
        @NotNull
        private String name;
        
        @NotNull
        private Integer type;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Document> createDocument(@RequestBody Document document){
        return new ResponseEntity<Document>(documentService.createDocument(document), null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Document> updateDocument(@RequestBody Document document){
        return new ResponseEntity<Document>(documentService.updateDocument(document), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Service**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Document updateDocument(Document document) {
    log.info("Deleting document with id: {}", document.getId());
    documentRepository.deleteById(document.getId());
    log.info("Saving updated document with id: {}", document.getId());
    return documentRepository.save(document);
}

@Override
public Document createDocument(Document document) {
    log.info("Saving new document");
    return documentRepository.save(document);
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código del controlador y servicio? Con lo que muestras no se puede ver de donde viene tu problema.

Comment: si, acabo de añadirlo @JoseHermosillaRodrigo

Comment: El problema es que estás eliminando y creando un registro nuevo que se generará con un nuevo identificador. Debe haber un método en la interfaz del repositorio de JPA para actualizar, pero tendría que buscarlo. Te lo mando como deberes :)

Comment: @AdolinK. no necesitas hacer un `deleteById` y eliminar un registro. Si le pasas una a entidad a `save` que ya tenga especificada la llave primaria, entonces no creará ningún registro nuevo, si no que actualizará el que ya existe. `save` es un método que sirve tanto para crear como para actualizar. Su comportamiento depende de que el objeto que le pases tenga o no tenga especificado el id.

Comment: Un poco offtopic. Tu implementación violaría la regla de que el verbo PUT de una API Rest debe ser idempotente. En ciertos entornos, por ejemplo, una cola de mensajería donde los mensajes pueden llegar desordenados, se suele generar el identificador desde el cliente, no desde el servidor ni tampoco desde la base de datos. Puedes leer más sobre idempotencia en este post: https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/06/29/rest-y-el-principio-de-idempotencia/

Comment: Tienes razon, no sabía que el método save permite actualizar registros, pero entonces tengo un problema, ya que el método save necesita tener especificado un 'id'. Si uso la anotacion de GeneratedValue me lo genera, pero tanto para crear como para actualizar una entidad, y esto no sería correcto. Tampoco puedo eliminar la anotacion, ya que entonces estoy obligando al usuario a que me informe el mismo el id que quiere crear, y esto no sería correcto @JaimeMenéndez

Comment: La anotación @GeneratedValue no interfiere en nada con el save. Repito, si le pasas un id que ya existe, ningún id nuevo va a generarse. Simplemente va a ir a la base de datos y actualizar el que ya existe. Cuando se crea un nuevo usuario, pasas el nuevo usuario sin id, puesto que lo que quieres es crearlo. Cuando quieres actualizarlo, lo pasas con id. Omitiendo validaciones, tus métodos create y update en tu controlador podría verse exactamente igual y funcionarían sin problemas como esperas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si como dices, se crea un nuevo usuario sin pasarle el id, habría un problema, ya que el id suele ser una clave primaria (se anota con @Id) y si no tiene ninguna estrategia de generación de id asociada, intenta crear el nuevo usuario sin el identificador, y esto provoca fallo.

Comment: Solo te haz la prueba en tu entorno y veras lo que te digo. Deja la entidad justo como la tienes y reescribe tu metodo update con el mismo código que tienes en create. Cuando te digo “se crea un nuevo usuario sin pasarle el id”, me refiero a que hibernate sabe y es lo suficientemente inteligente para saber que si el objeto que le pasas no tiene id, tiene que usar la estrategia de GenerateValue que definiste en tu anotación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue hacer la llamada al método deleteById, ya que elimina físicamente mi registro, y mediante la anotación de `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` se me genera el siguiente ID.

No es necesario realizar el borrado, el .save() de JPARepository es lo que me permite volver a actualizar mi registro con mi ID.